# Object disappear from 3d view but show in outliner and edit mode is disable

Tags: objects, visibility

Object disappear from 3d view but show in outliner and edit mode is disable
what happen ? hundred of object are invisible

export to .stl and it still exists

[image]

[image]

Comment: are they not in the second layer?

Answer (score 0):

Could they be hidden? Try Alt-H with the mouse over the window in object mode.